# Sort an array of dictionary ( or array of custom model object ) keeping all optional values object at the end of an array

Tags: ios, closures, swift4

Facing an issue to sort an array of custom objects, requirement is :

1. Array containing model object
2. need to sort array but all objects ( keeping all optinals values object at the end of an array)
3. objects containing information should come first.

I tried this way:

```
let mSortedFlights = gatesFlightCardArray.sorted(by: { ($0.departureFlight?.flight_number != nil || $0.arrivalFlight?.flight_number != nil) && $0.departureFlight?.time!.localizedStandardCompare(($1.departureFlight?.time!)!) == .orderedAscending  })
                if mSortedFlights.count > 0 {
                    gatesFlightCardArray = mSortedFlights
                }
```

but it sorting data.
Provide your inputs.

Comment: What exactly do you want to sort by? Flight number or time or both? If both, which is the primary sorting criteria? How should departure and arrival flight be considered?

Comment: Also, if you give the code for the classes you want to sort, this would be helpful.

Answer (score 0):

The sort method should not sort out nil values. For example sorting this array of Int? keeps the nil values and sorts them to the end:

```
var a = [0, 10, 3, nil, 5, 7, 2, nil, 4]
a.sort { v0, v1 -> Bool in
    guard let v0 = v0 else {
        return false
    }
    guard let v1 = v1 else {
        return true
    }
    return v0 < v1
}
print(a)
```

The result looks as follows:

```
[0, 2, 3, 4, 5, 7, 10, nil, nil]
```

For your example, I was not sure, what criteria you want to sort by. So I built an example, you can work with. I sort the array first by flight number of the departureFlight, then by flight number of arrival flight.

```
let sortedTrips = trips.sorted { trip0, trip1 -> Bool in
    // Sort all trips where either arrival or departure flight are nil to the end
    guard let departureFlight0 = trip0.departureFlight, let arrivalFlight0 = trip0.arrivalFlight else {
        return false
    }
    guard let departureFlight1 = trip1.departureFlight, let arrivalFlight1 = trip1.arrivalFlight else {
        return true
    }
    // Sort by primary criterion of departure flight number
    if departureFlight0.flightNumber < departureFlight1.flightNumber {
        return true
    } else if departureFlight0.flightNumber == departureFlight1.flightNumber {
        // If the departureFlightNumbers of both trips are equal, sort by arrival flight number
        return arrivalFlight0.flightNumber < arrivalFlight1.flightNumber
    } else {
        return false
    }
}
print(sortedTrips, separator: "\n")
```

To try this out for yourselves, in addition to the sorting code also copy my classes and example data into a playground:

```
class Flight: CustomStringConvertible {
    private(set) var flightNumber: Int
    private(set) var time: String

    init(flightNumber: Int, time: String) {
        self.flightNumber = flightNumber
        self.time = time
    }

    var description: String {
        return "\(flightNumber) at \(time)"
    }
}

class Trip: CustomStringConvertible {
    private(set) var departureFlight: Flight?
    private(set) var arrivalFlight: Flight?

    init(departureFlight: Flight?, arrivalFlight: Flight?) {
        self.departureFlight = departureFlight
        self.arrivalFlight = arrivalFlight
    }

    var description: String {
        return "\(departureFlight?.description ?? "na") - \(arrivalFlight?.description ?? "na")"
    }
}

var trips = [Trip(departureFlight: Flight(flightNumber: 3, time: "10:45"), arrivalFlight: Flight(flightNumber: 9, time: "12:45")),
            Trip(departureFlight: nil, arrivalFlight: Flight(flightNumber: 9, time: "12:45")),
            Trip(departureFlight: Flight(flightNumber: 3, time: "12:45"), arrivalFlight: Flight(flightNumber: 5, time: "12:45")),
            Trip(departureFlight: Flight(flightNumber: 8, time: "13:48"), arrivalFlight: nil),
            Trip(departureFlight: nil, arrivalFlight: nil),
            Trip(departureFlight: Flight(flightNumber: 4, time: "11:31"), arrivalFlight: Flight(flightNumber: 9, time: "12:45")),
            Trip(departureFlight: nil, arrivalFlight: nil)]
```

Comment: well i have an array of objects containnig arrival and departure flight , i want to sort  objects using some criteria but if both arrival and departure object is optional then it should come at the end .

Comment: @ShobhakarTiwari In the code I posted for you, all objects where arrival or departure flight are nil are sorted at the end. The trick is to first check, if they are nil and only after that sort for other criteria.